# Как добавить ContextMenuStrip к ToolStripMenuItem?

Tags: c#

В общем у меня есть меню, и при нажатии на один из `ToolStripMenuItem`, хочу чтобы показывалось контекстное меню с моими кнопками. Как это можно сделать?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Если нужно повесить на `ToolStripMenuItem` именно `ContextMenuStrip`, то на `ToolStripMenuItem` повешайте событие `MouseDown` или `Click`, а внутри метода вызовите принудительный показ контексного меню:

```
private void toolStripButton1_MouseDown(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
{
   contextMenuStrip1.Show(Cursor.Position);
}
```

---

Другой вариант: Вставьте в `ToolStrip` `ToolStripSplitButton`, там есть возможность сделать выпадающее меню. Чтобы это меню открывалось не только по нажатию на стрелку, повесте обработчик на событие `ButtonClick`, и в методе вызывайте открытие выпадающего меню:

```
private void toolStripSplitButton1_ButtonClick(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
   toolStripSplitButton1.ShowDropDown();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Как вариант, если у вас окно фиксированного размера, то

```
private void МойToolStripMenuItem_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        contextMenuStrip1.Show(menuStrip1 , x, y);
    }
```

`COntextMenuStrip1` - ваше контекстное меню.
`x*y` - точка, в которой появится твое контекстное меню.
Можешь эти значения как нибудь из указателя мыши взять.

Comment: @Андрей Анфилец, Чтобы отформатировать код, выделите его мышью и нажмите на кнопку {} редактора.